# How to call electron-updater outside the main rendering process

Tags: angular, electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

Im creating a desktop app using [angular-electron](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron)
I'm using `electron-builder` for packaging that supports auto updates with [electron-updater](https://www.electron.build/auto-update)

Everything is working by calling the functions from the entry point `main.ts`

```
import {autoUpdater} from 'electron-updater';
autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();
```

---

I would like to call `checkForUpdatesAndNotify` from angular so the user can check for update manually by clicking on a button.
First, I tried with the same way i've done it in `main.ts` but the method couldn't be found.  So I'm trying to get it by the `remote`, but I'm still getting an error.

```
import { remote } from 'electron';

@Injectable()
export class UpdaterService {
  console.log('try update');
  remote.require('electron-updater').checkForUpdatesAndNotify();
  console.log('success');
}
```

---

```
uncaught TypeError: remote.require(...).checkForUpdatesAndNotify is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber._next (updater.service.ts:17)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:192)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:130)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:76)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:84)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:15)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)
    at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/throwIfEmpty.js.ThrowIfEmptySubscriber._next (throwIfEmpty.js:32)
    at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was `remote.require('electron-updater').autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()`